# How can i make my request run in background while filling other EditTexts (Thread)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to threading but I have an EditText view which whenever is getting out of focused it fills a RecyclerView with image logos using the user's input from EditText. But, whenever the user gets out of focuse and the method is called everything stops for a while(which mean im bad at threading). How can I improve this code so it can run smoothly?

My activity class:

```java
public class addItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoadingDialog loadingDialog;
    RecyclerView imgList;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
    BitmapAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       /*
       / Code Unnecessary to the problem…
       */
       et_title.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if(!hasFocus){
                getImageLogo(et_title.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private void getImageLogo(String serviceName){
        googleRequest googleList = new googleRequest(serviceName);
        googleList.start();
        try {
            googleList.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Interrupted Error","Thread Was Interrupted unexpectedly",e);
        }
        if(googleList.getImgRealList() != null) {
            bitmapList.clear();
            bitmapList.addAll(googleList.getImgRealList());
        }else {
            bitmapList.clear();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

My googleRequest class:

```java
public class googleRequest extends Thread {

    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imgRealList;
    private final String keyword;

    public googleRequest(String keyword){
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImgRealList() {
        return imgRealList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String newKeyword = keyword.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        newKeyword = newKeyword.replace(' ','+');
        String url = "https://www.google.gr/search?bih=427&biw=1835&hl=el&gbv=1&tbm=isch&og=&ags=&q="+ newKeyword;
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            imgRealList = new ArrayList<>();
            Elements imgList = document.select("img");
            for (int i=1;i<imgList.size();i++) {
                if(i==8)
                    break;
                String imgSrc = imgList.get(i).absUrl("src");
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                imgRealList.add(bitmap);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By this line: `googleList.join();` you are blocking the main thread that will cause hangs in UI. Most of IO requests must be asynchronous that is, you request data and return immediately then the IO source respond with a callback that deliver the result. And you must implement that callback in order to deliver the result that obtained in a background process to the UI.

Comment: Since you are a beginner to threads this is one of the most handy ways to handle async operations. Let me show you an example implementation.

Comment: @Kozmotronik So if i use another thread to keep track of googleList it should stop blocking UI? Let's say i use another thread that waits for googleList to join and then runOnUIThread to update view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be implemented using a callback as I have mentioned in comments. For this, we need to define a callback inerface I named it as following, you can change the names for your convenience.

**RequestConsumer** it is simple java interface.

```java
/// Must be executed in the UI (main) thread.
@MainThread
public interface RequestConsumer {
    void onRequestResult(List<Bitmap> bitmaps);
}
```

**googleRequest** thread class.

```java
public class googleRequest extends Thread {

    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imgRealList;
    private final String keyword;
    /*
    We will use the request consumer callback in order to deliver the results
    to the UI from background. Since we need to touch the UI by this callback
    we ensure that it will execute within the UI thread's queue using the
    uiHandler.
    */
    private final RequestConsumer requestConsumer;
    private final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public googleRequest(@NonNull String keyword, @NonNull RequestConsumer requestConsumer){
        this.keyword = keyword;
        this.requestConsumer = requestConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String newKeyword = keyword.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        newKeyword = newKeyword.replace(' ','+');
        String url = "https://www.google.gr/search?bih=427&biw=1835&hl=el&gbv=1&tbm=isch&og=&ags=&q="+ newKeyword;
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            imgRealList = new ArrayList<>();
            Elements imgList = document.select("img");
            for (int i=1;i<imgList.size();i++) {
                if(i==8)
                    break;
                String imgSrc = imgList.get(i).absUrl("src");
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                imgRealList.add(bitmap);
            }

            // I think according to your code; the data you've requested is ready
            // to deliver from now on. But attention! we post it to execute it in the UI thread
            uiHandler.post(() -> requestConsumer.onRequestResult(imgRealList));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**addItem** activity class

```java
public class addItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoadingDialog loadingDialog;
    RecyclerView imgList;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
    BitmapAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       /*
       / Code Unnecessary to the problem…
       */
       et_title.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if(!hasFocus){
                getImageLogo(et_title.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private void getImageLogo(String serviceName){
        googleRequest googleList = new googleRequest(serviceName, images -> {
            // Here we get the delivered results in this callback
            if(images != null) {
                bitmapList.clear();
                bitmapList.addAll(images);
            }else {
                bitmapList.clear();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
        googleList.start();


    }
}
```

**Note** I've written it in a text editor so the code needs some function test.

Comment: Your implementation worked like a fine aged wine. I get that you created an interface on which we pass on the activity the result we want to do (you used a notation MainThread which i didnt know about it, So thanks for that ;) ). But can you explain a little bit the handler? Does it pass the resulted list to the interface and then executes the result method?

Comment: This is the `runOnUIThread`  method does in an activity. Since I don't know where you want to implement the `googleRequest` class, I just want to make sure that it works for any case. If you implement the `googleRequest` class as an inner class of the activity, you can use `runOnUIThread` instead of the handler since the `runOnUIThread` is a method member of `Activity` class. Other wise you must use a `Handler` class which works tied to the main thread's looper by passing its constructor parameter with `Looper.getMainLooper()`